# create a form which save data in sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to create a form with submit button which can save the inserted data to SharePoint 2010 custom list. I prefer to do this with CEWP web part and java script code
I searched a lot and found 2 relevant pages:
1- 
http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/10/03/create-contact-form-using-ecmascriptjavascript-client-object-model-sharepoint-2010/
and
2- 
http://www.niteenbadgujar.com/2010/04/how-to-insert-item-in-sharepoint-list.html

but after implementation does not any work in SharePoint.
can anyone help me what is the problem?

Comment: Show us your implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use InfoPath. Create a simple InfoPath form with a Submit, upload to it Central Admin, associate it to the Custom List. Then open that form, and upon Submit, it will store the information in that list. You can even promote fields that will auto populate columns in your custom list after the form has been submitted.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by it did not work , did it throw any error?

by default sharepoint blocks the excution of ecmascript , you need to enable it first.

else it will throw below error

> Error:The method “GetItems” of the type “List” with ID {..} is blocked
>   by administrator on the server

for details check below this [link](http://sharepointkid.com/errorthe-method-getitems-of-the-type-list-with-id-is-blocked-by-administrator-on-the-server/)

if you have already enabled it , please provide additional details.

Comment: thank you for your answer. yes the error is: failed. message:unexpected response from server. the status code of response is '0' . the status text of response is ". also I did not enable ecmascript for my SharePoint site.